# Convert C++ files to C# project

Tags: c#, visual-c++, c++-cli

I have a C++ file and I want include it in my C# project. Is there a way to add it to the C# project?

Answer (score 1):

To use C++ from C# you need to define a half-managed, half-native interface in C++/CLI. C++ is not callable from anything other than itself for a variety of reasons.

So create a C++ project, enable the CLR and define classes and methods that can be used from .NET. There should be plenty of resources around the web on how to do so.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can I know where to enable the CLR and how to define classes and methods?